# How getservbyname can get the server port information if it is run on a client machine?

Tags: linux, network-programming, ubuntu-10.04

The following client program trys to connect to a server and finds the current time and date on that server.

```
/*  Start with the usual includes and declarations.  */

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *host;
    int sockfd;
    int len, result;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    struct hostent *hostinfo;
    struct servent *servinfo;
    char buffer[128];

    if(argc == 1)
        host = "localhost";
    else
        host = argv[1];

/*  Find the host address and report an error if none is found.  */

    hostinfo = gethostbyname(host);
    if(!hostinfo) {
        fprintf(stderr, "no host: %s\n", host);
        exit(1);
    }

/*  Check that the daytime service exists on the host.  */

    servinfo = getservbyname("daytime", "tcp");
    if(!servinfo) {
        fprintf(stderr,"no daytime service\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("daytime port is %d\n", ntohs(servinfo -> s_port));

/*  Create a socket.  */

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

/*  Construct the address for use with connect...  */

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = servinfo -> s_port;
    address.sin_addr = *(struct in_addr *)*hostinfo -> h_addr_list;
    len = sizeof(address);

/*  ...then connect and get the information.  */

    result = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, len);
    if(result == -1) {
        perror("oops: getdate");
        exit(1);
    }

    result = read(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    buffer[result] = '\0';
    printf("read %d bytes: %s", result, buffer);

    close(sockfd);
    exit(0);
}
```

**Question:**

We run the above program on a client machine, how the function getservbyname can get the
server information without a reference to the server machine in the parameter list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getservbyname` simply looks in `/etc/services` to find the "daytime" service using the "tcp" protocol.

It's just a convenience, to save you from parsing that file.

#### Edit (clarification)

Each of these protocols has a friendly name ("daytime", "http", etc) and a useful name (the port number - 13, 80 etc). `/etc/services` holds this mapping, nothing more.

Comment: Do you mean the daytime service is same as server and client machine?

Comment: @q0987 I mean it's just a **standard** port number (and a L4 protocol).

Answer (score 2):

It examines `/etc/services` for an entry with the given service name and protocol.

```
$ grep "^daytime\s.*/tcp" /etc/services 
daytime         13/tcp
```

Comment: This is the part that I feel confused. Assume that I provide a hostname in the comand line for the server machine name. This client in fact doesn't acqure the service of datetime from that provided server machine instead it gets the info local from the file /etc/services. In other words, we make assumption that both server and client share the same service information. Is that correct?